# HLSL - What Does int(x) or int(value) do in High Level Shading Language 2.0?

Tags: c, gpu, hlsl

I've been asked to port some old HLSL code (Shader Model 2.0/3.0) into another language.

There is a line in the code that reads -  `int(value)` or `int(x)`.

But it doesn't seem to be a "convert to integer" or "return integer of" or similar command.

Anyone know what `int(x)` does in older versions of HLSL?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: ///////////

The line in the code reads:

`x = int(x / 12) * 12;`

it seems intended to "step" or "toon" the value of x...  this should be the same as using the 2 code lines;

```
int x2 = x / 12;   
x = x2 * 12;
```

right after another but the result comes out different - the rendered image screws up completely when I use the 2 line version. I may be able to remove this line completely and replace it with something else... its not a very crucial operation... but I'm curious to know what

`x = int(x / 12) * 12;`

actually does to the value of x under HLSL Shader Model 2.0/3.0. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What makes you believe that it is not an `int` cast?

Comment: please do not put relevant code into comments, [edit] it into your question, so others can see it immediately (also so it can be formatted properly)

Comment: Fixed. Added code example to main question. Thanks.

Comment: Surely it is cast, asint() would be more sensible.

Comment: Your two line expansion is wrong -- the second line should be `x = x2 * 12;`

Comment: I actually mistyped that while editing. Have been porting code for 8 hours, so tired, sorry. =) I have just removed this portion of the code and replaced it with some simple math that gives roughly the same visual result. This HLSL shader was written using HLSL in MPC-HC media player. So maybe the compiler MPC uses interprets the line differently from normal HLSL compilers. Anyways, the line is gone now.

Comment: Your latest edit is still different from the original code - `x2 = x2 * 12;` should be `x = x2 * 12;`

Comment: Noted. Thanks. Fixing original post now.

Answer (score 0):

It's a construction cast, just like in C++ or C# -- in general `type(arg)` converts the argument to `type`, by constructing a value of that type from the argument (or arguments).